# Effect of a long char as a primary key

Tags: mysql, indexing

I am planning a database which has a mini chart of accounts.  My account codes are names like:

- CURRENT_DEBTORS
- CURRENT_CREDITORS
- CASH_AT_BANK

I am thinking of using the account codes as a primary key in the account database, which would mean it would be a foreign key in a transactions table.  The field would be something like CHAR(20) in MySql.  The transactions table would get about 10,000 entries per month.

How will this long-ish character index affect performance?  I can use a surrogate key if I have too, but would prefer not too.  (I'm not too worried about disk space, of course).

Comment: Is that `CHAR(20) utf8`?  If so, that takes 60 bytes.  Make it `CHARACTER SET ascii`, if appropriate.

Comment: There are times when a 'natural' PK is actually faster and smaller than adding a surrogate `AUTO_INCREMENT` PK.  One example is when there is no secondary key.

Answer (score -1):

Technically, the answer to your question is that won't have a huge impact on performance, but it will have some, and you would need to test it on your system to know the real impact.

Practically, however, the answer is: don't do it that way. Store those codes in a table, give each a unique integer id (an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column) and make that integer your foreign key. That's properly normalized, uses much less space than an extra `CHAR(20)` in every row, and will impose much less of a performance hit.